# Creating an image carousel using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I would like to create an image carousel using plain JavaScript and HTML. I have been able to move to the next slide with the logic I have but having trouble with the previous slide functionality. When going through the next slide the slideshow at the end restarts at the first picture. I would also like to have this behaviour with the previous slide functionality going to the last picture instead of receiving a Uncaught TypeError.

How can I achieve this ?

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".div-container")
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next")
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".previous")
let currentIndex = 0;

const nextSlide = () => {
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"
  }
  currentIndex++
  if (currentIndex > slides.length) {
    currentIndex = 1
  }
  slides[currentIndex - 1].style.display = "block"
}

nextSlide()

const prevSlide = () => {
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"
  }
  currentIndex--
  slides[currentIndex - 1].style.display = "block"
}

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextSlide()
})

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  prevSlide()
})
```

```css
.div-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}

.image {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div-container">
    <button class="previous">Previous</button>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src="https://i.redd.it/z7myrlhfhxr31.jpg" alt="windows xp autumn" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src="https://www.newegg.com/insider/wp-content/uploads/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg" alt="windows xp bliss" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/tjkelly.com/wp-content/uploads/windows-xp-desktop-background-wallpaper-follow-800x600.jpg?ssl=1" alt="windows xp fishy" class="image">
    </div>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code with as little changes as possible. Instead of two separate functions I am now using just one for stepping forward and backward:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".div-container")
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next")
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".previous")
let currentIndex = 0;

const nextSlide = (inc) => {
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"
  }
  currentIndex=(currentIndex+slides.length+inc)%slides.length;
  slides[currentIndex].style.display = "block"
}

nextSlide(0)

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextSlide(1)
})

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextSlide(-1)
})
```

```css
.div-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}

.image {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div-container">
    <button class="previous">Previous</button>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src="https://i.redd.it/z7myrlhfhxr31.jpg" alt="windows xp autumn" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src="https://www.newegg.com/insider/wp-content/uploads/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg" alt="windows xp bliss" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/tjkelly.com/wp-content/uploads/windows-xp-desktop-background-wallpaper-follow-800x600.jpg?ssl=1" alt="windows xp fishy" class="image">
    </div>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

The central part of the operation is the expression

```
currentIndex=(currentIndex+slides.length+inc)%slides.length
```

It calculates a new `currentIndex` by adding `inc` to the current value. `inc` can be -1, 0 or 1 and the resulting value will always be between 0 and `slides.length-1`.

There is scope for further improvements (code simplification and reduction of global variables), but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just check in prevSlide function if currentIndex is zero and set it to slides.length:

```
 currentIndex--
if (currentIndex === 0) {
 currentIndex = slides.length
}
```